# I’ve had a phone call to say I’ve got job but still waiting on contract etc

Tags: communication, job-offer, contracts, notice-period, time

I interviewed last Tues and called on Thurs to say I’ve got job.
It’s now a week and no contract and details etc..
I told them I needed to give notice.
How long before I start chasing??

Comment: My advice here is do NOT give notice at your current position until you have everything needed from the new job including a start date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: All comments and answers are great so far. I also want to mention that you should continue to apply for other jobs and go to other interviews if you already have plans for those. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest you should have asked about timescales when they phoned to offer the job! Having said that it's perfectly fair to make a polite enquiry after a week.

Answer (score 2):

To build off the comment by @jwh20, I once had a verbal job offer, but it fell through because they did not have enough money.

Feel free to follow up in a few days to a week, and do not give any notice until things are in writing.

If they gave you a tentative start date, That should be delayed if the delay due to them.

Comment: I had an offer in writing once that fell through because the day I was supposed to go in and do new hire paperwork, the upper management told the people that tried to hire me they were laying people off instead of hiring.  Nothing is ever guaranteed, even in writing. This is not an argument against what you said, just felt it was worth pointing out.

Comment: @coppereyecat in that case, depending on the jurisdiction, you probably were entitled to some compensation (possibly minimal, like the minimum notice pay for instance)

Comment: @JeffUK Possible, although I wasn't able to get anything from unemployment since I voluntarily quit my previous job to take the new one that fell through.... also because I put in my notice and they told me to just work the rest of the week, so I didn't work the full notice period. It was a mess but worked out okay in the end.